# How can I see which answer's reputation is affected by a user being removed?

Tags: support

There's a -10 rep notification on my profile due to a user being removed. It's clear that the upvote is erased if the upvoter isn't with us any longer.

I'm curious if, and if so how, I can see which question is the subject of the reputation adjustment. Clicking on the link leads me to my profile only (which scared the rest products out of me because I first thought that it was me who's been removed).

Comment: No, it's deliberately not shown so it's harder to guess which user was the one removed.

Comment: I am really curious why you would want to know. Because I can't think of a single reason, not from a perspective of usefulness or a perspective of curiosity. What am I missing?

Comment: @yivi I understand. That poses a new question, though. What's the motivation behind preventing the removed user to be recognized? Am I missing a patter of misconduct here?

Comment: Voting is anonymous. Anonymity should be preserved, even if the user is removed.

Comment: @Gimby Not sure if I understand. I saw the score being removed and noticed a though in my mind: "*ah, okej... I wonder which question it regarded*". That is the curiosity perspective. Not sure how I can explain the emotion. It's just there. I guess our minds dwell on different aspects. Regarding the usefulness, I can't see any reason neither. However, that wasn't an objective in my question. Only the curiosity part was. Perhaps's it's like jazz - some people love it. I can't see a single reason to listen to that and get mostly stressed by the sound of it.   :)

Comment: @yivi Ah, that's a valid point. I haven't ever thought of that. We have the question of why we'd like to keep it anonymous, of course, but I'm not curious about that. Some people prefer to *pass judgement from the bushes* (i.e. voting without a trace). Admittedly, a good democratic principle. I'm not objecting. And, as Gimby mentioned, there's nothing of practical gain in knowing that detail. Thanks!

Comment: @KonradViltersten That's the thing: it regarded no question at all. The user was removed. If that user had upvoted 5 of your questions (or answers), an upvote would have been deducted from all of them. It's just boring and very neutral bookkeeping, it doesn't affect the content in the slightest. So that made me wonder why you would want to take a pilgrimage to the place of origin of the reputation loss.

Comment: @Gimby If a post gets an upvote, you're told which post it was. If it gets an un-upvote, you're told which post it was. Same for downvotes. It's only natural to want to know which post it was where a vote was removed.

Comment: @Scratte I think it's largely a matter of taste or personal inclination. What's natural to you (and apparently to me) might be weirdly unfamiliar to someone else. I sometimes get baffled and think *how can you not see that?!* only to realize that *oh, that's **my** opinion...*. It's a good opinion but in the end, it's mine only. (Regrettably...)

Comment: I agree with you on that. What I don't agree with is making it sound like there should be no interest in it. The site is using gamification to make people work and contribute, and making it out as if that shouldn't effect anyone, despite the fact that it clearly affects most people, seems to me to be very questionable.

Comment: @yivi How would anonymity be affected in this case? I assume that you do not get a notification which exact user was removed.

Comment: @stackprotector Because it would be easier, in some circumstances, to infer which user was the one removed. No, you would not know for certain which user, but you'd have more information to perform an informed guess. This is mentioned on the answer on the duplicate.

Comment: @Scratte I fully agree with your sentiment. Please take a look at what I wrote again and read a bit more in-between. I rather assume a mild, understanding and humble tone despite my actual interpretation being a bit more... skeptical... I too found the formulation confrontational and imposing. But I can imagine that it's a unfortunate choice of words and unintentional directness. (Then again, I can imagine a lot of things, not actually being true.) I'm sure that it made sense to the regarded user to state what they did. Otherwise, they wouldn't state it, right?   :)

Comment: @yivi To be honest, I find the motivation for not disclosing the question being unvoted rather weak. On the other hand, the practical usefulness of me knowing it is rather limited, as well. Deciding which interest trumps the other is a bit of a competition between dwarfs. Undeniably, I wanted to know. Admittedly, I regret asking about it. But it is kind of unexpected that I get notified about votes but not unvotes.  :)

Comment: The good news is that it's possible to make a user script to do it. The bad news is that it's going to be somewhat convoluted and must keep all scores to compare new with old. For someone like me that's not a lot, but for you.. that's a little more in storage. For those that post 20 times a day.. perhaps a database would be better :)

Comment: Come to think of it perhaps it doesn't need to be that convoluted after all. You could "just" download the [raw reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) often enough and then make a direct text-comparison to get the postId. If you decide to make a script, please post it on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com) :)

Comment: Or use Data Explorer as long as you catch it before the refresh

Comment: @Scratte I promise I will post it if I make such a script. **If...** It's a bif *if*. But the link you provided, that's a new to me. I wasn't aware of such a thing at all. Interesting...

Comment: @KonradViltersten Feel free to pop into the [Userscript newbies and friends](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends) chat room :)

Comment: The difference between a user being removed and an up-/downvote or unup-/downvote is that the latter are content-rating actions and so it makes sense to denote the affected post (eg. you edited an answer and someone unupvotes it, so maybe the edit made it worse). The former is not about the content, but the user and the invalidation of votes on your posts is merely a side-effect. Also don't underestimate the possibility of people making a correct informed guess on who voted for what after a known event like an account deletion.

Comment: @JeanneDark It could be (will sufficiently much stretch, though) that it's useful to see which of my posts pull attention of unreliable users who are removed. (NB, a stretch, admittedly.) As the other point of yours, while I find it valid, I see a poor proportion between the consideration for a removed user's anonymity. It's rather easy to figure out in other cases, so why protect it here? And even if we find out who the user was, so what? The accounts are not linked to a social security number and the user can easily hide by not disclosing any information. In my way, it's exaggerated.

Comment: Because on SO it's about the content, not the user. And, for example, an unupvote may hint at a problem with the content after an edit and so may be good to know. Account removal is not linked to one's own content, so knowing more about it may satisfy one's curiosity but not be helpful and why waste dev time on that? It's also not primarily about the removed user's anonymity, it's about the anonymity of voting and its protection. Why should this be potentially compromised for no gain to anyone involved?

Comment: @JeanneDark I realize that I failed to convey my point. Let me try again. (Prefix each upcoming statement with *in my opinion*, please.) We don't risk compromising anything. There's nothing to compromise because the information isn't there. It's a profile not a real person. Some people have several ones. Most of them are not linked to any sensitive info. There's no "loss" there. It is of gain to the people involved, satisfying the curiosity of (still remaining) users.

Comment: @JeanneDark Removing an upvote due to change tells me something. True. Knowing that an upvote by someone unreliable who's been removed is also telling me something. It's not actively done by the user, sure. But it's the unupvote that's the point of mine. Frankly, I sense that there's a flaw in the design but we're creating the motivation to fit it. There's no integrity to be protected (not a real person). There's inconsistent information presented. I simply don't buy it. (I don't care much about that, neither, to be honest. I just disapprove of poor explanations.)   :)

Comment: Anonymous voting is one of the tenets of SO. Not even mods can see who voted. Everything potentially compromising it is very problematic. Also (and again), SO is about content, not users. A vote or retracted vote gives you information about content, a vote removed because an account was deleted doesn't, just possibly about the removed account. That's the decisive difference - *content* in the case shown now, *user* in the case now hidden.

Comment: @JeanneDark Thank you for the explanation. I notice that you keep repeating that it doesn't provide about the content, while I keep pointing out that it does. It seems to me, also, that you leave out the part that whatever anonymity is provided at deletion of the user, it's not offered for up/down votes in general (due to deduction). I tried to elaborate, fearing that I was unclear on my point but I understand now that the clarity isn't the issue. I'm going to conclude that you won't address the points I make and drop the exchange as pointless. Debate is rarely gainful. Discussion is. Regards.